# custom image dimensions (for gallery)

Tags: images

when uploading an image into the mediapool, wordpress will auto-resize it in several dimensions. 
unfortunately i'm requiring a special format which is kinda between thumbnail + medium.
any ideas if it's possible to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call add_image_size in your functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'medium', 240, 160, true );
```

Reference here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: And you might be interested in looking at the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin so that you can get your custom size for images you've already uploaded: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/